# Filtering tables from read_html based on regex attr

Tags: html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I know how to filter based on exact id with the help of the attrs parameter.

```
tables = pd.read_html(url, attrs={"id": "box-CHI-game-basic"})
```

I don't know the exact ID in advance, I know the structure of it. I could capture id with regex:

```
re.search(".+-game-basic", "box-CHI-game-basic")
```

It doesn't work if you just add the regex as the value of the attr.

The match parameter of read_html can use regex, but it goes through the whole text, I would like narrow it down to the id.

Comment: You use regex in `match='.+'`, not in `attrs`. See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html?highlight=read_html)

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I know that, but I would like to narrow the search only to ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with `pandas_html`.

The `match` parameter will match:

> The set of tables containing text matching this regex or string

As for `attrs`, what you're attempting won't work becasue

> `attrs` is a dictionary of attributes that you can pass to use to identify the table in the HTML. These are not checked for validity before being passed to lxml or Beautiful Soup. **However, these attributes must be valid HTML table attributes to work correctly**

So, I guess you'd have to resort to `bs4` first, for example:

```py
soup.find_all("table", id=re.compile(".+-game-basic")
```

And then, pass the table to `pandas` for further parsing.